# Creating images with Android Asset Studio using iPhone images

Tags: android, image, android-layout, image-scaling, image-size

I have the iPhone / iPad images from an already created application.
Now I would like to create the images for Android using the tool 
[Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/).

Which is the best approach ?

- Creating the Android images using the images from iPhone 6 Plus (@3x)?
- Using the images from the iPhone 6 and iPhone 5 (@2x)?
- Or from iPad 2 and iPad mini (@1x)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For better results, **all** of them.

**1x** images should go into the `drawable` folder.
**2x** ones into the `drawable-xhdpi` folder, and
**3x** ones into the `drawable-xxhdpi` folder.

In alternative, `to save some apk size`, you could use only the **3x** ones and put them into the `drawable-xxhdpi` folder.
Android will do its best to scale them down.

Comment: as far as I know, Android has all these folders: drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-tvhdpi, drawable-xhdpin drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi.... then , for the rest ?

Comment: No - it hasn't, by default. YOU provide them, **if necessary**. The missing graphics will be scaled (from a bigger one, if existing OR from a lower one, in this order). The preferred direction is bigger to lower, since it will perform a pixel scaling (blending) rather than adding pixels (pixellation). This respects common sense also when scaling a picture in a graphical editing program.

Comment: `drawable-hdpi` would require a graphics scale of **1.5x** and `drawable-ldpi` would require a graphics scale of **0.75x**. Luckily, `drawable-xxxhdpi` is the **less used** (at the moment), requiring a graphics scale of **4x**. `drawable-tvdpi` is something inbetween `drawable-mdpi` and `drawable-hdpi` (a bit closer to the latter) - it's only used in tv devices.

Comment: Yes, but. The xxxhdpi ones will be stretched (so, suffering of pixellation - even by starting with the **3x** ones). And they all would be saved at the **standard** density of 72 dpi. (I would instead recommend saving each set to its proper density: xxhdpi at 480 dpi, for instance).